# Updated to Windows 11 insider release (2021-11) and now my WSL2 Ubuntu 18.04 isn't loading. What to do?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04, windows-11, recovery, windows-insider

My computer just updated to the latest windows 11 insider release and now My WSL2 ubuntu 18.04 isn't loading. How do I go about debugging why it just hangs when I start it up? I even tried going to the command prompt and type in bash and it just hangs. What is the issue?

Comment: Have you tried installing another distro and starting that?  Is it only your Ubuntu instance that fails, or all WSL2 distros?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I start up a cmd window and run: wsl --shutdown

After that it's good to go and I just re-open my wsl terminals.